# is there a way to ask NAT its IP address from a host connected to it?

Tags: networking

I know I can do this by ask google what is my IP and similar services but I don't want to use third party services. I don't have administrative rights to the NAT. I'm looking for some kind of request or packet that I can send to my NAT it replies me with it's IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i assume here that by NAT you mean the address on which all the traffic is routed. Here the case is NATing is done onto your router so all your devices will have an external ip that of your router. If you want to know the ip of the devices that is NATed onto your router for that there is no easy way but somehow you have to have gain access to your router's translation tables (where the mappings and connection states are kept), then indeed you can learn about your internal IP.

But knowing about the IP here i assume your NAT ip that is the public ip of your router. You have to use external application. Or you can use traceroute in cmd it will also give your external ip.

Comment: With CGN, the public IP address is not necessarily the IP address assigned to the router's WAN interface by the ISP. In that case, the public IP address is one assigned to an ISP router. CGN creates a double-NAT.

Comment: thank you Ahmed. yes I'm looking for my public IP and I don't want to use external application, can you please elaborate how can I use this treaceroute in cmd?

Comment: open your cmd and then first ping to google

ping www.google.com -t

*lets suppose ip is 1.1.1.0
once you have obtained their external ip we would be using it as an input to tracert command

then open another cmd window and type:

tracert 1.1.0.1 

and you will be given a trace from your ip to googles and in that case you will see ur routers external ip too

Comment: But @RonMaupin have a very valid point. It must have been possible that there is double NAT going on.